# Android firing intent from thread

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a thread for a game where I am testing if hero (a bitmap) touches the edges of the screen.

Part of the Thread:

```
protected void updatePhysics() {
mBallX += elapsed * mBallDX;
        mBallY += elapsed * mBallDY;

        if((mBallX <= 0 & mBallDX < 0) | (mBallX >= mCanvasWidth - mBall.getWidth() & mBallDX > 0) ) {
            mBallDX = -mBallDX;
            updateScore(1);

        }
    }
```

This is from a tutorial. Instead of updateScore(1) I want the game to be over and open the GameOver activity. 
I am using this code in other activities but here in the thread it shows an error:

```
Intent intent_btn_gameover = new Intent(GameThread.java, GameOver.class);   
startActivity(intent_btn_gameover);
```

*The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type GameThread* and it does not like GameThread.java (*The constructor Intent(GameThread, Class) is undefined*). I don't know what to set as the first parameter of the Intent.

Thanks

**Edit**:

```
private Context gContext;
```

and

```
Intent intent_btn_nextlevels = new Intent(gContext, GameOver.class);
startActivity(intent_btn_nextlevels);
```

Error: *The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type GameThread*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of Intent's constructor is a Context. You must pass the activity where the Thread is being executed, for instance:

```
Intent intent_btn_gameover = new Intent(NameOfActivity.this, GameOver.class);   
startActivity(intent_btn_gameover);
```

If the thread is not inside an activity, you must pass somehow a reference to the activity that executes it.

Comment: The thread is a separate class like: public class GameThread extends Thread{

Comment: Then add a constructor to that thread where you receive a Context and send a reference of the activity that created that thread. Then, use that context to initialize the `Intent`.

Comment: `gContext.startActivity(intent_btn_nextlevels);` try to read a tutorial for beginners before doing advance stuff.

Comment: @Cristian I really hate your comment:  try to read a tutorial for beginners before doing advance stuff. Why don't you learn some manners?

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting an activity from your Thread and you have context  then you should do like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(contextOfSourceClass,YourTargetActivity.class);
contextOfSourceClass.startActivity(intent);
```

because method startActivity(Intent intent) belongs to context class

we are able to call this method directly from our activity because Context is super parent class of Activity in Hierarchy.