# Send Intent from Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

**What I try to do**

---

Hello Guys, I'm trying to create a Login-Screen which is connectet to my server. For this I created a Method which is in a other pakage than my Activity. I use this Method in my Activty and it works like a charme.

Now the Problem starts, when I try to pass a Intent back from my Method (Thread) it isn't possible. How can realize that?

For this I also searched Stackoverflow first and found this post: [pritty much the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393809/android-firing-intent-from-thread) but I don't get how this should work so I ask again.

**Question**

---

So to my question. I'd like to know how can I pass an Intent from my Thread to my Activity. I'd like to do this really simple. If you have some Sample's or a good tutorial, I please post it in the awnsers!

Down here i'll provide you the code you need to get what i'd like to do.

**Code**

---

Datahandler

```
package de.ivocore.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import de.ivocore.LoginActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataHandler {

    /** LOGIN-Methode
     * Für diese Methode muss ein "final String username" sowie ein "final String password" mitgegeben werden
     * Die Methode fürt die Login-Prozedur mit dem api.i-v-o.ch durch.
     * Zurückgeben wird die Response welche vom Server kommt (Login erfolgreich oder nicht), sowie der Sessionkey.
     *  */
    public void JSONLogin(final String username, final String password){


        Thread t = new Thread(){                                                            //Neuen Thread definieren


            public void run(){                                                                  //Startet automatisch wenn der Thread gestartet wird, führt die Funktion aus


                String URL = "CENCORED";                                        //URL definieren für JSON-Post
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                                     //HttpClient definieren (DefaultHttpClient(); ist speziel optimiert für Android, darin ist auch der Timeout definiert)
                HttpResponse response;                                                                  //HttpResponse definieren, handelt den http response
                JSONObject login = new JSONObject();                                                    //JSON-Object welches gesendet wird

                try{
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);                                                  //HttpPost definieren, handelt den http post
                    login.put("username", username);                                                    //Füget dem JSONObject Login den Username ein
                    login.put("password", password);                                                    //Fügt dem JSONObject Login das Passwort ein



                    String test = login.toString();     Log.d("JSON", test);    


                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+login.toString());
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    //post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    //hkgvjpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


                    response = client.execute(post);


                    /** Response-Checker
                     * Hier wird gecheckt was wir in der Response bekommen
                     */
                    if(response != null){                                                               //Hier wird geprüft ob etwas in der Response ist

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                                         //Stringbuilder um aus dem Response einen String zu erstellen
                        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));   //response vom inputstreamreader lesen und in einen bufferedreader einfügen um diesen anschliessend zu einem string hinzuzuzfügen und in ein json object umwandeln

                        String line;                                                                    //String definieren darin ist die später die response
                        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {                                        //Hier wird definiert das der String Line den inhalt vom bufferedreader ist, der duchgand wird mit readLine durchgeführt
                            sb.append(line + "\n");                                                     //Hier wird der string line nach \n gesplittet (newline)
                            }

                        String result;                                                                  //String result definieren
                        result = sb.toString();                                                         //Hier wird der inhalt vom Stringbuilder zum String result hinzugefühgt
                        Log.d("DataHandler", "Append String " + result);                                

                        if(result != null){                                                             

                            try{
                                final String userid;
                                JSONObject holder = new JSONObject(result);                             //Result in ein JSONObject konvertieren
                                userid = holder.getString("id");

                                Log.d("JSON-Response", userid);

                                final Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class); --> THIS DOSN?T WORK!
                                i.putExtra("ID", userid);


                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("DataHandler", "Cannot read JSON"+e);
                            }

                        }


                    }

                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DataHandler", "Cannot Estabilish Connection"+e);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();                                                                                      //Thread starten

    }
```

---

Thx for your help in advance

Have a nice day!

Comment: Dont use threads, use an asynctask...

Comment: a async task is ways to overkill for this

Comment: it is very easy to use and it is not overkill at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `final Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class); 
                                i.putExtra("ID", userid);`
 with

```
Message progressMsg = new Message();
                        progressMsg.setData(your bundle);
                        handler.sendMessage();
```

add handle in class like below :

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, newActivity.class); 
        i.putExtra("ID", userid);
    }
};
```

hope useful to you...

Comment: or better i ask how can i receive the value of that message in my Activity`??

Comment: use "sendMessage(your message)" and in handler get that message.

Comment: could you post it to your anwser, I don't get it.. :(

Comment: check edited code you can pass message or data using bundle and retrieve bundle in handler using getData().

Comment: Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
 in your handler and from there if you want to pass these data to newActivity then pass as this bundle using putExtra method of intent.

Comment: Allright so in my DataHandler.class I send the Message. Than I can receive it in my LoginActivity.class over the handler again

Answer (score -2):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put it in postexecute method.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/